# react-native : Flatlist Performance issue and repeated re rendering onChangeTextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am implementing a chat application in which all the messages in the chat window are rendered with the help of FlatList. After getting the View hanged and freezed, when i did some research i added the PureComponent to make it work better. But even after making the renderItem component a pure component, there is no much difference in performance. How to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
                <FlatList
                ListEmptyComponent={this.renderEmpty}
                data={this.state.messages}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                extraData={this.state.sent}
                keyExtractor={(item) => {
                  return item.id;
                }}
                ref={(ref) => (messagelist = ref)}
                onContentSizeChange={() => this._onContentSizeChange()}
                onRefresh={this._handleRefresh}
                refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
              />
```

renderItem():

```
renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
     return (
      <MyListItem
        onLongPress={() => this.showActionSheet(item, index)}
        index={index}
        uid={this.state.uid}
        item={item}
      />
    );
  };
```

onChangeText

```
  onChangeText={(text) => {
     this.setState({ txtMessage: text });
    }
```

sendMessage:

```
      sendMessage() {
    let { uid } = this.state;
    this.setState({ sent: true });
    var receiverType = CometChat.RECEIVER_TYPE.USER;
    var textMessage = new CometChat.TextMessage(
      uid,
      this.state.txtMessage,
      receiverType
    );
    this.setState({
      txtMessage: "",
    });
    //CometChat.endTyping(typingNotification);
    CometChat.sendMessage(textMessage).then(
      (message) => {
        this.setState((state) => {
          return state.messages.push(message);
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        this.setState({ spinner: false });
        console.log("Message sending failed with error:", error);
      }
    );
  }
```

What happens is everytime when user inputs something in the  when onChangeTextInput is invoked, re rendering occurs n times where n is the number of messages rendered in the Chat window. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: can you share the full code with the onChangeTextInput and the states in your component ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan updated onchangeTextInput, Actually the state sent is changes when user sends some message and i have given it to extraData. But, it re renders everytime eventhough the value of sent isn't changed.

Comment: still hard to see how the array and onchange text are connected :(

Comment: Added sendmessage fully. I can share you a gist with the full page code if you can have a look at it.

Comment: generally this can be fixed by using the keyextractor, if your ids are unique then it should not re render, also you have a spinner does it cover the whole screen or something ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan Nope. Its a flatlist with cometchatpro sdk integrated. I have followed the same example : https://github.com/cometchat-pro-samples/react-native-chat-app But there its not made into separate components.

Comment: your code is using a spinner, better check the setstate calls in your code

Comment: but why does it re renders, eventhough i have given the correct extraData value @GuruparanGiritharan

Comment: can you create a snack that we can test this out ?